# WebView表示のボタン押下時の処理は？

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin

AndroidでWebView表示の中のボタンを押した時にprotected fun isNativeEvent(uri: Uri): Booleanが呼び出されました。WebView表示のボタンを押した時の処理はここに書けばよいのでしょうか？

[カスタムWebView](http://it-trick-java.appspot.com/android/c2015/page5002.html)というものも見つけました。

```
public interface EventHandler {

    // support methods

    protected fun isNativeEvent(uri: Uri): Boolean {

        //WebViewからボタン押下時
        return uri.getScheme() == "native-event"

    }

    protected fun targetUri(uri: Uri): Uri {

        return Uri.parse(Uri.decode(uri.getQueryParameter("url")))

    }

    protected fun isGoogleDomain(uri: Uri): Boolean = Constants.isGoogleDomain(uri)

    public fun handleEvent(uri: Uri): Boolean

}
```